# High quality specular reflections on Android

Tags: android, unreal-4

I opened the Unreal Editor VR example, imported the TwinMotion materials and set the floor to a nice parquet. In the editor it looks like this:

[image: Good reflection]

However when I run it on my Oculus Quest it looks like this:

[image: Bad reflection]

It's a little hard to see in this example because of the weird artefact on the floor, but the reflections are much lower quality. It seems like the bump maps aren't being used at all.

Is there any way to fix that? (Bonus points if you can tell me what is going on with the grey overlay, which doesn't show up in the preview.)

Comment: This looks like a level of detail optimization. The engine is drawing the nearby portion of the floor with a high-quality material, and falling back to a lower-quality material for the rest of the floor, using dithering to hide the transition. This is likely to try to preserve bump mapping detail close to the viewer where it's most noticeable, while keeping the rendering cost manageable. It looks though like the near material is having some kind of compatibility problem, so it's not being shaded correctly. If you can fix that, I'd suspect your specular quality will look better in that region.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The OpenGL ES preview shows the lighting problem but without the weird bug. It doesn't depend on distance.